# Two bar graphs in the same place, controlled by one slider D3.js

Tags: jquery-ui, graph, d3.js, slider

I am attempting to create a bar graph that when independent sliders are moved they change two bar graph svg heights at the same time and they are stacked, they are different colors show it shows two separate values in the same graph, basically showing growth vs the current. I am using jquery-ui and D3.js. Currently it only moves the one svg elements instead of both at the same time, Id like them both to move at the same time.

HTML

```
<div id="slider" class="slider">
  <label for="amount">Age</label>
  <input type="text" id="amount1" style="border:0;  font-weight:bold;">
</div>

<div id="slider1" class="slider">
   <label for="amount2">Retirement Age</label>
   <input type="text" id="amount2" style="border:0;  font-weight:bold;">
</div>
```

JS

```
//initialize sliders

jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

$("#slider").slider({
  max: 100
});
$("#slider").slider({
  min: 18
});
$("#slider1").slider({
  max: 100
});
$("#slider1").slider({
  min: 18
});

//slider actions

$("#slider, #slider1").slider({
  value: 10,
  animate: "fast" ,
  slide: function (event, ui) {

    //capture the value of the specified slider

    var selection = $("#slider").slider("value");
    var selection1 = $("#slider1").slider("value");

    //fill the input box with the slider value

    $( "#amount1" ).val( selection );
    $( "#amount2" ).val( selection1 );

    //set width and height, actually I'm a little confused what this is for

    var w = 200;
    var h = 200;

    //data arrays for svgs
    var dataset = [];
    var dataset1 = [];

    //fill the data arrays with slider values
    dataset.push(selection);
    dataset.push(selection1 + selection);

    //draw rectangle on the page
    var rectangle = svg.selectAll("rect")
    .classed("collapse", true)
    .data(dataset);
```

**

> THIS IS WHERE IT CONFUSES ME

**

```
    //I draw the second rectangle here, however I choose the same svg element,
    //Im not sure what other way to get it to appear in the same space but
    //I am sure this is what is causing my issues
     var rectangle1 = svg.selectAll("rect")
    .classed("collapse", true)
    .data(dataset1);


    //not sure what this does
    rectangle.enter().append("rect");
    rectangle1.enter().append("rect");

    rectangle.attr("width", 200).transition().attr("fill", "#A02222").attr("height", function (d) { console.log('d is ' + d);
    return d;
    }).attr("x", function (d) {
      return 40; //I dont know why I return 40?
    }).attr("y", function (d) {
      return 40;  //Same here dont know why I return 40?
    });

    rectangle1.attr("width", 200).transition().attr("height", function (d) { console.log('d is ' + d);
    return d;
    }).attr("x", function (d) {
      return 40; //I dont know why I return 40?
    }).attr("y", function (d) {
      return 40;  //Same here dont know why I return 40?
    });

  }
// slider actions ends here
});

//Create SVG element
var svg = d3.select(".svgContain").append("svg").attr("width", 125).attr("height", 300);

});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For starters, you may want to follow this tutorial: http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3886208

The "return 40;" that you are wondering about are actually what will specify the position and dimensions of the rect's you're appending to the svg. Those shouldn't just be 40, they should be bound to values in the data set, or based on the index of the bar's series in the set of series or something more meaningful than 40.

There is a stacked bar chart data processor that will take a set of series and spit out a new set of series coordinate definitions that make it easier to calculate how rect's will stack in svg coordinate space: https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Stack-Layout

Then, there's the more general issue of how to deal with these "nested" data sets where you have series, and in the series there are values and you don't want to have to manually track and select individual series. There are several ways to handle this sort of situation. If you know you will only ever have two series, and you really want fine-grained control over each independently, you could assign the top level object an id and then start the data join for each of the plots by selecting that top level object by id... eg:

```
var container1 = d3.select("#myContainer1);
container1.selectAll("rect").data(myData1).append("rect");

var container2 = d3.select("#myContainer2);
container2.selectAll("rect").data(myData2).append("rect");
```

If you do something like that, the first select basically sets the context of the subsequent selects. So, only the rects inside of the "#myContainer1" or "#myContainer2" will get selected by each "selectAll" based on which context you're in.

The other approach is to use nested selections. Nested selections are a little more complicated to wrap your head around, but 90% of the time, this is the approach I use. With nested selections, you would restructure your data slightly and then apply nested selects/joins to bind each series to a dom element and then the values of each series to subelements of each of the series dom elements.

First, read this: http://bost.ocks.org/mike/nest/

and then try making your data something more like this:

```
data = [
    { key: "series1", values: [...]},
    { key: "series2", values: [...]}
];
```

Then, you will want to do a nested selection where you start with a selection of the "data" array and bind it to whatever svg or html element you have that wraps each of the two series.

```
var series = d3.select("svg").selectAll("g.series")
    .data(data, function(d){return d.key; });

series.enter().append("g").attr("class", "series");
```

At this point, d3 will have added a "g" element to your svg element for each series and bound the series object (including the key and values array) to the appended elements. Next, you can make a nested selection to add series-specific elements to the g element... ie:

```
var rect = series.selectAll("rect").data(function(d) { return d.values });
rect.enter().append("rect");
```

Note that we used a function in our ".data(...)" call. That's because the values we want passed to the join actually depend on which specific series is being processed by D3.

Now, you'd have a rect added to the g element for each value in each series. Since you used d3 to do the data binding and you used the key function in the first select (".data(data, function(d){return d.key;}"), future selects done in the same nested/keyed manner will update the right g and rect elements.

Here's a **Fiddle** that demonstrates the concept: 
http://jsfiddle.net/reblace/bWp8L/2/

A key takeaway is that you can update the data (including adding additional series) and the whole thing will redraw correctly according to the new nested join.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed and timely response. That Article is very useful. It will take me a while to process this information. Thanks for your time.